# stacktrace: ["org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: compound sub-files must have a valid codec header and footer: file is too small (0 bytes)

Tags: elasticsearch

Recently, we have been encountering the "CorruptIndexException" frequently, accompanied by the following **stacktrace: "org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: compound sub-files must have a valid codec header and footer: file is too small (0 bytes) (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(NIOFSIndexInput(path="/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices/UAS5VDw1Sv6xrrrvoN39Bw/1/index/_52.kdm")))"**.

Upon checking the "_52.kdm" file, we found that it actually contains 143 bytes. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue?

We are currently using Elasticsearch version 7.17.5 and spring-data-elasticsearch version 4.4.2.